# @Builder groovy AST transformation

Tags: groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I am looking for Groovy AST transformation that would generate builder pattern code inside my class.

I know there are something like `@Canonnical` or `@ToString` or `@EqualsAndHashCode` enhancers that automatically generate useful methods and hoped if there would be @GenerateBuilder. I want to use it something like this:

```
//Groovy code:
@GenerateBuilder
@CompileStatic
class Person  {
    String name
    int age
    Long id
    String createdBy
}

//then in Java code:
Person p = Person.newBuilder()
    .withName("pawel")
    .withAge(19)
    .withId(11123)
    .withCreatedBy("system")
    .build();
```

Comment: I found some groovy ast examples, as one can see, it is not so hard to write your own transformation, but I hopped if there is ready solution :) http://groovy.dzone.com/articles/groovy-ast-example

Comment: Hope [these samples](https://gist.github.com/dmahapatro/5e35e59cad2736a6723f) help in support to Tim's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing prior to 2.3 that will do this

But groovy 2.3 has a new `@Builder` annotation

https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/transform/builder/Builder.java

Comment: I have to dig deeper for hidden treasures like this in latest version. Managed to create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dmahapatro/5e35e59cad2736a6723f) about it. Hope that helps OP. :)